# Packing a Chrome Extension crashes on a Mac with a "Bus error"

Tags: macos, command-line, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Packs fine interactively via chrome://extensions but this command:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --pack-extension=chrome_ext/src-development/ ----pack-extension-key=chrome_ext/src-development.pem  --no-message-box
```

Crashes Chrome with a

```
Bus error
```

Chrome 9.0.597.94
OSX 10.6.6

Answer (score 1):

Does this still happen, this shouldn't happen? If so can you file a bug please with detailed steps? http://crbug.com/new

Once you do, please comment back so I can place proper tags so Chromium devs can triage it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I added appropriate tags for that bug.

Comment: Yes, the bug has been fixed :) Thanks for the report!